# How to modify a serialized protobuf byte array in place?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Consider a protobuf message:

```
message DataMessage {
    int32 custId = 1;
    string uuid = 2;
    int32 version = 3;
    string firmName = 4;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp date = 5;
    int32 accountNo = 6;
    string firmName = 7;
    bytes payload = 8;
}
```

I populate this and Marshal it to a byte array and publish this as a Kafka message. All this works wonderfully.

Now to the question: the Kafka handler gets the byte array. What I'd like to do is modify fields 2 and 3 *ONLY* without having to unmarshal the byte array back into a DataMessage, modify fields 2 and 3 then marshal it back into another byte array so it can be Kafka published to the next hop. Field 3 is a string but is an ISO-formatted GUID. The modification here will not increase or decrease the field length.

`protob.Buffer` doesn't seem to facilitate this. It seems to allow encode/decode on single fields at a time.

The payload (field 8) is 99% by size and won't be modified. I'd like to skip all the temporary copies and marshal/unmarshal work to modify the 1%.

Possible? I guess if I knew the offsets into the byte array for fields 2 and 3 I could use modify the bytes in place ... however this undermines the integrity of the marshaled bytes to some extent. This might be made easier by using fixed32 instead of int32 ... so the offsets into the byte array are consistent.

Comment: It's pretty dangerous to modify the bytes of a protocol buffer. As far as I know, the ordering of the fields is simply an implementation detail. So while one library might put them in order of their field number, another might put them in an entirely different order. For example, if you look at the spec for repeated fields you'll see that the elements of the repeated field aren't even guaranteed to be next to each other in the serialized format.

Comment: You might be able to simply append an extra almost-empty payload with **only** fields 2 and 3. This is definitely meant to work for the integer. There is, however, a possibility that the string will interpret this as meaning "append this string". You could append an extra value after a sentinel token (comma?) And just take the last such if you see multiple?